# Refreshing View for changing order in android grid-view

Tags: android, gridview

I'm using grid view to show, list of users. I have spinners at the top to change the order of list. When I select order by name, the order doesn't changes. But when I scroll grid view down then again go-to top the order was changed according to my selection.

Now I want my list view to show the change right after I select any option from spinner.

Comment: whenever any selection happens use notifydatasetchanged() internal method to indicate listview to refresh its views

Comment: Didn't understand your answer. I'm using my list<objects> to populate data in gridview.